# Adding Steam OpenID?

Tags: feature-request, openid

Just wondering if it's worth adding the Steam OpenID Login to the list, [like on the Gaming SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/)?

Comment: -1: I don't really think it would serve a purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't it serve the same purpose as all the other openID logins?

Comment: It would, it's just a shortcut in case people use Steam a lot. It made sense for Gaming, so I suggested it in case there are many Steam Users on GameDev. If not, then not.

Comment: If it wouldn't be huge efforts, then it would benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Would be great because Steamworks is very popular among developers today.